# Separate front-end application for hyn/multi-tenant package

Tags: laravel, nginx, eloquent, multi-tenant

Any help would be really appropriated on how to achieve this.

I have currently three separate applications, two front-ends running with vue.js and one backend app, with laravel tenancy, only serving API's, no front-end.

The main base URL or the backend url is set to example.com, this is the tenancy application. It auto-generate URL subdomain.example.com for tenants & databases, as the tenancy package works.

Another domain setup for secure.example.com that points to the another vue application, where we register. Works perfectly well.

Now I have a third application on vue.js, for the tenant's, that points to anything to *.example.com,
and the way the tenancy works, is that wildcards & directory must be set to the main application where tenancy is installed, for the tenancy to work with subdomains.

I cannot create *.example.com & point it to the vue application, as the API calls, then go to vue application not to the back-end, as the sub-domain *.example points to vue application

The whole point is to separate the Tenant UI entirely using a frontend framework like vue.js from the back-end.

Comment: I would personally make use of regular expression and make sure if there is anything with a dot before ```example.com```, should be treated as a subdomain otherwise its the main domain

Answer (score 0):

Im using Quasar separated from the Laravel Api, with the Hyn Multitenant package..

> brightmind-erp.com
>
> demo.brightmind-erp.com

In public/panel from Laravel public folder I'm inserting the dist assets from Quasar, and redirecting '/' calls to that route where Vue Router enters in action:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return redirect()->route('frontend');
});

// Route everything else to Vue
Route::get('panel/{any?}', function () {
   return file_get_contents(public_path().'/panel/index.html');
})->where('any', '.*')->name('frontend');
```

If you're using Webpack you have to configure it to find the Vue assets from (in this case) '/panel' folder....

I fought with a lot of tutorials to configure .htaccess file or nginx config to make the api work in '/api' route and vue in '/' but I couldn't

Comment: Thank you Walter for sharing your knowledge. What we actually want to do is to host the entire front-end on a different server. Doing it with in Laravel with vue is quite easy, as it is one base project, and all the routes & api's goes to a single app, from nginx.

Comment: I can't understand your problem .. If you host the frontend in other server you'll have another domain and consume the api from *.domain for that tenant..

Comment: I'm working on it & i might get into solution which I will definitely share with the community.